# Dynamic creation of objects based on DB entrys

Tags: c#, dynamic

Working in C sharp.
I have made a panel with many objects as textboxes, checkbox, dateTimepicker and so on. I want these to be filled by a database entry. That part is ok. The thing I'm having a hard time figuring out is how to make new instances of the panel with objects based on the number of entrys in the database.

If you look at MS outlook, the emails are listed with topic, sender, and have flag button and so on. The more email, the longer the list, and scrollbar. I want my software to do kind of the same thing.

If you look at my scetch there are two panels that could show my data. I want one to be created and filled with data from my database based on the number of entrys.
See scetch at www.hagafoto.no/dreiekunst/scetch.jpg

I'm know this is a big amount of code, but could anyone point me in the right direction on topics to search for, and learn more about. 
Any help appriciated!
// Thomas

Answer (score 0):

To point you in a direction you can take:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.AutoScroll = true;
        int i = 0;
        Mypanel[] p = new Mypanel[10];
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            p[j] = new Mypanel();
            p[j].Location = new Point(0, (i++) * 80);
            this.Controls.Add(p[j]);
        }
    }
}

public class Mypanel : Panel
{
    Label label1 = new Label { Text = "first" };
    Label label2 = new Label { Text = "second", Location = new Point(0, 30) };
    public Mypanel()
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.White;
        this.Height = 60;
        this.Controls.Add(label1);
        this.Controls.Add(label2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Just what I needed to get started.